# Use PerformancePoint to show server availability

Tags: 2013, performancepoint

Is there a way to show show a graph of server availability by using PerformancePoint?

We'd like to be able to show a constantly updated graph (every 10 minutes or so) of whether certain servers are up. Is this possible through PerformancePoint? We are using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You could build something like this in PerformancePoint, but it would not be a simple task.  OOTB it won't poll your servers for uptime.  You would need something to poll the servers, that would write to a data source (SSRS) for PerformancePoint to read from.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to clarify something, the PerformancePoint service in SharePoint is not related measure SharePoint Performance or its server availability.

> PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint Server is a performance
> management service that you can use to monitor and analyze your
> business. By providing flexible, easy-to-use tools for building
> dashboards, scorecards, and key performance indicators (KPIs),
> PerformancePoint Services can help individuals across an organization
> make informed business decisions that align with companywide
> objectives and strategy. Read more at [PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint Server overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/performancepoint-services-overview?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)

So it's just a SharePoint BI tool to visualize and show the data in SharePoint and as I earlier mentioned it doesn't help to build a graph for server availability without the existence of such data sources that hold info about server availability.

In case, you are data source is available and you just looking for a BI tool inside SharePoint. so you have to use PerformancePoint service. *[Check Using PerformancePoint Dashboard designer in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/view-ssrs-report-using-performancepoint-in-sharepoint/)*. However, you may find some difficulties and limitations in this tool, **So** it's recommended if you have a license to use Power BI Report Server or SSRS 2016. check more about this at

- [Install SSRS 2016 step by step](https://debug.to/999/install-ssrs-2016-step-by-step)
- [Install and configure Power BI Report Server step by step](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/install-and-configure-power-bi-report-server/)
- [Install and Configure SQL Server Reporting Service (SSRS)](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/install-and-configure-ssrs/)